# Solution Virtualization not Supported, BIOS missing virtualization option?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, cpu, bios, virtualization

In my system BIOS virtualization option is missing. After research found that my system doesn't support virtualization.

**Laptop model :** HP DV6-1152TX **Processor :** Processor type - Intel Core 2 Duo Processor T6400 * 2.0 GHz, 2 MB L2 Cache, 800 MHz FSB **BIOS version :** F.25 **Operating System :** Windows 8.1 pro 64 bit

Please let me know best way to resolve this issue? If I have to change the CPU what are the specifications I need to consider? Does virtualization is essential for Cloudera Quickstart VM. Is there some way one can use Cloudera Quickstart VM without using virtualization or upgrading BIOS and CPU.

Thanks,

Comment: 32-bit virtualization can be performed without the VT-x extensions, but it appears that the Cloudera product is not released in 32-bit versions.

Comment: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch10.html#hwvirt

Answer (score 6):

[Your CPU](http://ark.intel.com/products/40479/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-T6400-2M-Cache-2_00-GHz-800-MHz-FSB?q=T6400) does not support virtualisation. To get virtualisation to work you would need to replace it with a CPU which supprts VT-x, which works in your laptop (not quite trivial!) and your motherboard firmware (EFI or BIOS) will also need to support it.

Practical solution: A new laptop.

Comment: It's almost certainly impossible to upgrade the CPU in this specific laptop. +1 for an accurate answer and the correct (practical) solution. CPU was released seven years ago, time to upgrade to a modern system.

Comment: Thanks, is virtualization essential to run Cloudera Quickstarts on VMWare or virtual box. Can you run Cloudera Quickstarts without virtualization?

Comment: @cool, no, that product is a Virtual Machine, so the only way to run it is in a virtual platform provider like Virtualbox, VMWare, Xen, Docker, etc.

Comment: @cool don't lose hope just yet, if my memory serves, you should be able to switch off the hardware vt-x acceleration option for virtualbox, leaving you with full software virtualization.  I don't have VirtualBox installed at the moment, but there is definitely an option to turn Vt-x off in the settings.

Comment: @Hitsugaya198, I'm afraid that the vbox manual does explicitly state that software virtualization cannot be used in conjunction with an x64 guest. It is unfortunate.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running the VirtualBox version?  I see that your CPU is 64-bit, and that the Cloudera runs on 64-bit.  I don't see a requirement for the VT-x extension listed on the Cloudera web site (and from my limited understanding that is mostly needed if you want to run a 64-bit virtual machine on a 32-bit host).
I would download the Cloudera version for VirtualBox and try it.
Hope that is helpful.

REFERENCE: http://www.cloudera.com/developers/get-started-with-hadoop-tutorial.html

UPDATE:  Found this link suggesting resetting the BIOS to default would make the option show.  However, you may need to download a BIOS update and flash your BIOS to the new version.  Link below
http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Hardware-and-Upgrade-Questions/HP-Pavilion-dv6-enabling-VT-x-in-BIOS/td-p/656627

Comment: Could you possibly include a reference from the requirements page?

Comment: I was wrong.  According to VirtualBox, you MUST have the VT-x enabled in order to run a 64-bit system.  Also, on the requirements page I referenced above, you must have at least 2 virtual processor cores, which also requires the VT-x to be enabled.<br><br> I'm new to superuser, should I delete my answer? I feel as if it gives clarity, even though it doesn't provide the answer the OP was requesting.

Comment: @Burgi I posted the reference page I found with the "requirements".

Comment: Hi Guys, Thanks for all your replies wanted to add few things. Both in oracle virtualbox and VMWare 64 bit option is freezed I could only select 32 bit option. Now when I am trying to initialize cloudera quick start cdh it is crashing or not initializing. If system virtualization is not necessary or is not the issue behind the closing of quick start virtual machine, then how can I fix it and start using quick start virtual machine. Few post says virtualization is not necessary and few says its necessary. I am confused and not finding correct path.

Comment: Unfortunately, it appears as though virtualization is necessary.  You may need a new laptop if a BIOS update does not fix the issue.